# How do I prevent my forced marriage?

Tags: marriage, philippines

I'm an 18 year old girl in Philippines studying in a college.

My father wanted me to marry to someone and already arranged it without even asking me. But I don't want to marry.

I'm 18 now, can law help me in any way?  Am I independent to marry at my own will?

Comment: As much as I sympathise with your story, this website isn't for getting specific legal advice. See a lawyer. If you are above the age of majority for your country you should be able to live independently and alone.

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks - Really? Most of the questions on here seem to be for advice/answers about specific legal situations...

Comment: @colmde This site can answer specific questions about what the law says. Questions of the form "What should I do?" go one step beyond that and are considered off topic, partly because there may be important facts that the OP has not mentioned and partly because of fear of being blamed if things go wrong.  Sometimes people will post answers with suggestions about what to do despite this, but its dodgy ground.

Answer (score 7):

The legal solution is very simple. Under [Philippine law](http://www.chanrobles.com/executiveorderno209.htm#.Xifl5iN7kxs) (Title 1, Marriage, Article 2)

No marriage shall be valid, unless these essential requisites are present:

> (1) Legal capacity of the contracting parties who must be a male and a
>   female; and
>
> (2) Consent freely given in the presence of the solemnizing officer.

If you do not consent to the marriage during the ceremony, that is the end of the matter, you are not married.

You can also refuse to apply for a license under article 11 (which requires your sworn application – refuse to swear). If your are threatened with violence, you can report this threat to the police, since not even your father is allowed to threaten to assault or kill you.